# C# Handling Exception Message Template in Config File

Tags: c#, app-config

I have functions that sends out email messages using specific string formats for different messages.

Below is a sample:

```
String BodyText = "Information \r\n \r\n ID: " + id + " \r\n \r\n Title: " + title + " \r\n \r\n Description: " + description"
```

As the messages contain variables, is it possible for my message to be configurable in the config file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. You could parse variables in a string from config, giving something looking like this:

   My email here is sent to {{firstname}} etc.

   To implement this, you could do a regex search to inject variable values into your symbols ie `{{firstname}}` or alternately you could look at implementing something like the visitor gang of four pattern which will make a more unit testable setup where each variable is additive to code, as opposed to part of a hard-coded blob that needs modifying each time a variable is introduced.
2. You could use Roslyn to pull the code in from config and just compile it on the fly. I would highly not recommend this due to the security and zillion error scenarios that could occur.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) and put your string into the config file like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BodyText" value="Information \r\n \r\n ID: {0}\r\n \r\n Title: {1}\r\n \r\n Description: {2}"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then you can use the value in code like this:

```
var bodyText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BodyText"];
String.Format(bodyText, id, title, description);
```

Note, you will need to add a project reference to `System.Configuration` and then add the corresponding `using` statement to the file.